# Backup docker volume or only mysqldump

Tags: mysql, docker, backup, docker-volume

I have an mysql instance running in a docker container. I mount a volume in `/var/lib/mysql` to preserve the data after shutting down the container. I think i have two options to backup my database to my host system:

1. Backup the complete volume:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from db -v {BACKUP_PATH_ON_HOST_SYSTEM}:/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/mysql
```

2. Only backup a mysqldump

Basically run above command but instead of backing up the volume i create a mysqldump which i would copy to `/backup`.

Which option is better?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement. In my case, I'm using an old `mysql` Docker image on purpose like so:

```yaml
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_SITE_NAME}_mysql
    volumes:
      - db_files:/var/lib/mysql
      # Load the initial SQL dump into the DB when it is created.
      # This only runs once if the DB is empty.
      - ${SQL_DUMP_FILE}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASS}
      ...

volumes:
  db_files:
    name: ${COMPOSE_SITE_NAME}_db_files
```

If the volume is lost, then it can be recreated with a dump file. In my case, I prefer to make a dump file instead of preserving the cacophony of SQL files in that `/var/lib/mysql` folder.

```
docker-compose exec db sh -c '\
  mysqldump -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --all-databases --routines --triggers \
' | gzip -c > /path/outside/docker/backup-`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.sql.gz
```

This will create a compressed dump file on your host outside Docker due to the stdout redirect (`>`). I use the `sh -c ''` so I can reuse the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` env var in the container. Feel free to adjust this to suit your MySQL requirements, like specifying a limited user.

With the default flags, the dump file will have `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` statements so you can replace an existing DB without deleting the volume (`docker-compose down` then `docker volume rm ...`).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise **not to** give up SQL-based backups in favor of docker volumes backups (for database data)!

While it might be tempting to do that (easy to setup and automate) you should bear in mind **it does not** guarantee that you will retrieve your data. Docker volume dump will not only contain data but also its structure (which is not universal among all platforms).

One example I can give where it might not work is when you want to use your docker volume dump on a different disk. Say, for example:

1. You have your docker container (with SQL server) on machine `M-1` and volume on persistent storage (disk) `D-1`
2. You want to setup another containerized server on machine `M-2` with disk `D-2` (assume that this one has more space than `D-1`
3. While formatting `D-2` you used different block size than on `D-1`
4. You dump your volume on `D-1` to *.tar* and want to load it to the volume on `D-2` (e.g. from production to development)
5. You run your server on `M-2` and expect it to work

And it's likely that it just won't. Moreover, the error messages might be misleading and debugging painful. The worst part is that sometimes it might work, sometimes not (depends on [disk formatting](https://linuxize.com/post/fdisk-command-in-linux/) in this case).

Looking at [official MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker-mysqldump) they suggest the approach with `mysqldump` for dockerized servers (it would be unwise to ignore them).